# How can I see the birthplace of "Lord British" in Cambridge?

Tags: sightseeing, england

Richard Garriott (known as Lord British in Ultima computer games) was born in Cambridge, England in 1961. Is the street address of his home at the time published anywhere? The best I could find is this tweet, but the address is not given:

https://mobile.twitter.com/richardgarriott/status/817881525333135360

> Walked from the house I was born in to the home of Stephen Hawking in Cambridge today, to give him a copy of my book for his 75th birthday!

That suggests a possible range of locations, but I am looking for a street address.

Comment: Local tourist offices can often be a source of information on relatively obscure tourist ‘attractions’ in their area. You could try contacting the Cambridge Tourist Information Office to see if they know where the location you’re looking for is situated. https://m.visitcambridge.org/information/contact-us

Comment: It doesn't really suggest much of a range other than "somewhere in Cambridge". Few places in Cambridge are more than about an hour's walk apart and most of the city is within about 45 minutes' walk of the centre. Also, why do you assume that his childhood home in the 1960s has any relation to where he was living 50-plus years later in 2017?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't find any record of Richard Garriott's (or parents') address in Cambridge, and I don't think it is a very large city, so the fact that he walked to Prof. Hawking's house does not say much.

But from this Cambridgeshire County Council page about [births, marriages and deaths](https://www.cambridgeshire.gov.uk/residents/births-deaths-and-marriages/certificates-&-family-history/) you can make a search for the birth certificate of Richard Garriott, born 1961 in Cambridge, which turns up the record shown below. I can't see the actual record (you can buy a copy) but my own UK birth certificate records the address where my parents were living.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that UK birth certificates record not only the mother's address, but also (separately and explicitly) the [place of birth](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Specimen_England_and_Wales_Long_Birth_Certificate.jpg).

Comment: @Pont, maybe things changed at some point, or maybe there's some metonymy around birth certificates vs entries in the register of births. My UK birth certificate (the document given by the registrar to my parents to certify my entry in the register) doesn't name my parents or include any geographical reference narrower than the city.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's true that only the short birth certificate has ["Birth Certificate"](https://www.rootschat.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=h196b1g4ahiq9mqtfup12aegh4&action=dlattach;topic=717351.0;attach=418828;image) explicitly printed at the top, but the UK government currently seems to [use the term for the longer document as well](https://www.gov.uk/register-birth/birth-certificates).